# How to Resize Images in Infobox in Mediawiki?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions, mediawiki-templates

I managed to create an infobox in my Mediawiki after performing hours of code as I am a beginner, but now I am facing issue with the image resizing in that infobox. In other words, I want to resize the image which I put in the infobox. I saw that in Wikipedia, we can achieve this by a code i.e.,

```
{{Infobox person
| image                     = 
| image_size                = 
| alt                       = 
| caption                   = 
}}
```

Here, the code `image_size` can help us to achieve this, I think so.
So, is there any parser function to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images support resizing in the `[[File:]]` syntax, the size can be passed via template parameter as well. See here for how to do it: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Images#Size_and_frame

Comment: thanks for your response. I already tried your way but it didn't worked for me. But no worries!, I found the cause of this. This was because of the structure of my short urls.

Comment: Anyways, I have another issue with my Mediawiki installation. If you can help then please response to this question  I asked. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60228468/mediawiki-infobox-and-mobile-frontend-in-mobile-not-showing-perfectly-how-to

Comment: Unfortunately I can't help you with these, I've never used MobileFrontend, but good luck!